# Google chart does not appear even if no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

Here is my code to create google chart from csv data. ANd also no error. But even chart does not appear.

Here is the documentation for which works: http://economistry.com/2013/07/easy-data-visualization-with-google-charts-and-a-csv/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
       // grab the CSV
       $.get("Chart1-data.csv", function(csvString) {
          // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
          var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
        alert(arrayData);
          // this new DataTable object holds all the data
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

          // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
          var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
          view.setColumns([0,1]);

         // set chart options
         var options = {
        title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
        vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
        legend: 'none'
         };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chart1-data.csv

```
Category,

A,34

B,23

C,14

D,57

E,18    

Other,5
```

Do I missing anything in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news: Your Code is fine! Your CSV file is the bottleneck.

1. Column names can't be null, means Category, => Category,''
2. No additional line breaks between data rows, means

A,34

B,23

=>

A,34
B,23

Result:

```
Category,''
A,34
B,23
C,14
D,57
E,18
Other,5
```

That is all! :)

Comment: thanks, but still it does not show anything on the page. No chart appears. Can you please test it on your system

Comment: I did and it worked well. I saw a pie chart. Where did you test yours? I put it on a local webserver because of the remote access to the csv file.

Comment: ca u plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508264/create-google-guage-chart-from-csv-data

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem any kind of problem with this Google chart code snippet.

Though in browser console there are some Uncaught JavaScript errors.
Most importantly there is 
" **Uncaught null** "error which is in reference to blank space after "Category" so **Category, ' '** should work fine

Comment: thanks, but still it does not show anything on the page. No chart appears. Can you please test it on your system